Populate one table from another with dynamic column value
I have table sec_profile. I want to populate table sec_status from sec_profile with certain columns.
I am using this SQL statement to do that:
INSERT INTO sec_status (ukey, sec_date, active_flag)
    SELECT ukey, sec_date,'Y'
    FROM sec_profile

This is working fine. As of now I am hardcoding active_flag = Y. I wanted to dynamically populate that flag based on sec_profile data.

if sec_date >= Today's date  then active_flag = Y
if sec_date < Today's date   then active_flag = N

I was able to do that using separate UPDATE statement however would like to know can this be done as part of my SQL ?

If I understand correct, you want a CASE expression? INSERT INTO sec_status (ukey, sec_date, active_flag) SELECT ukey, sec_date, CASE WHEN sec_date >= CURRENT_DATE THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END FROM sec_profile.

If the target column is supposed to hold more than 'Y', 'N' or a null, you can use the case statement already suggested by Jonas Metzler above or a union all of two selects with hardcoded y/n and corresponding where conditions. If it's just two values or a null, make it a boolean and feed it sec_date>=current_date directly.

The question doesn't state the desired behavior when sec_date is NULL. There is also no mention of NOT NULL constraints on either sec_date or active_flag. It is important to fully define how NULL state should be handled.
If sec_date IS NULL implies that active_flag should also be NULL, then the following can be used:
INSERT INTO sec_status (ukey, sec_date, active_flag)
SELECT ukey,
       sec_date,
       CASE
         WHEN sec_date < CURRENT_DATE THEN 'N'
         WHEN sec_date >= CURRENT_DATE THEN 'Y'
       END
FROM sec_profile;

If sec_date IS NULL implies that active_flag is 'Y', then change the CASE expression as shown below:
INSERT INTO sec_status (ukey, sec_date, active_flag)
SELECT ukey,
       sec_date,
       CASE
         WHEN sec_date < CURRENT_DATE THEN 'N'
         ELSE 'Y'
       END
FROM sec_profile;

If sec_date IS NULL implies that active_flag IS 'N', then do the following:
INSERT INTO sec_status (ukey, sec_date, active_flag)
SELECT ukey,
       sec_date,
       CASE
         WHEN sec_date >= CURRENT_DATE THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
       END
FROM sec_profile;

When sec_date is constrained to be NOT NULL, then all three CASE expressions produce the same result. The first INSERT statement will raise an exception if a NULL sec_date is encountered and active_flag has a NOT NULL constraint. The last two INSERT statements always assign a value to active_flag.
